# How Gradle decides from which dependency to take class if it present in more than one

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, dependency-management

I'm using Gradle and have 2 dependencies in my project:

```
implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version: '3.1.4'
implementation group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '5.0.2'
```

Both dependencies have a class WebDriver under the same package:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
```

Despite the order of these 2 dependencies in the build.gradle file when I use WebDriver the reference goes to the second dependency - java-client.

How does Gradle decide which dependency to use?
If I comment out java-client the reference goes to the other one (selenium-api - the one I expect to be used).

Playing around with versions of the java-client showed even more confusing results:

- while using a version less than 4.1.0 WebDriver class dependency is resolved correctly - from the selenium-api;
- while using version 4.1.0 and higher it is resolved to the java-client.

I can't figure out what is the rule here.
Or how can I specify a resolution strategy in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about the build tool and it's dependency resolution. From Gradle perspective those dependencies have nothing in common and are resolved independently.

Each dependency becomes an entry in the class path of the runtime, so which of the classes used is just a question of the class path order which is a bad idea in general.

Two different library artifacts differing in more than the version should not offer equal classes - except you really want to replace it and must never be used together like SLF4J wrappers. Instead they should change the package structure (see Apache Commons Lang e.g. moving package org.apache.commons.lang to import org.apache.commons.lang3 to avoid conflicts when included by transitive dependencies or prefixing repackaged classes).

In this case Appium did a bad job including Selenium classes instead of declaring a transitive dependency. You should not use both dependencies in one project module or will get unpredictable results especially if the implementations of the selenium classes differ. As far as I know this problem has been addressed in later versions of Appium, try to upgrade to version 7 instead of 5.